# Exploding date string into separate span elements in Ruby

Tags: ruby, datetime

I'm looking for the best way to take a datetime string from MySQL, explode it in Ruby and return the month, date, and year in separate  elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require 'time'
x = "2009/04/16 19:52:30"
begin
  y = Time.parse(x)
  [y.year, y.month, y.day]   # => [2009, 4, 16]
rescue ArgumentError
  puts "cannot parse date: #{x}"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

How is the string formatted? You could just convert the datetime string into a datetime object, and call the instance methods.

```
require 'time'
x = "2009/04/16 19:52:30" #grab your datetime string from the database and assign it

y = DateTime.strptime(x, "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S") #create a new date object
```

Then a simple y.day() yields:

```
y.day() = 16
```

and y.hour():

```
y.hour() = 19
```

FYI never actually used Ruby much, so this is what I got out of playing with the console, so hopefully this helps shed some light.